# BaseClientService.Initializer not found in google api .in c#

Tags: c#, google-api, google-analytics-api, google-api-dotnet-client

I am not  able to find these specific class **BaseClientService.Initializer** in google.API DLL. Actually, I am trying to fetch google analytics data using service account certificate, but when I create the service object, it requires IAuthenticator, here I need to create BaseClientService.Initializer object,

```
 string scopes = new string[] { AnalyticsService.Scopes.AnalyticsReadonly.GetStringValue() };
 ServiceAccountCredential credential = new ServiceAccountCredential(new ServiceAccountCredential.Initializer("xxx@gmail.com") {
                Scopes = scopes
            }.FromCertificate());
 var service = new AnalyticsService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
            {
                 HttpClientInitializer = credential,
                ApplicationName = "Analytics API Sample",
            });
```

Here is reference link, which I follow http://www.daimto.com/google-drive-api-with-a-service-account/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is a very old tutorial you should have downloaded the .json key file when you created your project in Google developer console.  This code is more updated [Google service account with Google Analytics](http://www.daimto.com/google-service-accounts-with-json-file/).

Gmail.com is not a valid service account email address.  You might also like to read my [Google developer for beginners service account](http://www.daimto.com/google-developer-console-service-account/) tutorial.

```
using Google.Apis.AnalyticsReporting.v4;
using Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2;
using Google.Apis.Services;
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates;

namespace GoogleAnaltyics.V4
{
    public class ServiceAccountJson
    {
        public string type { get; set; }
        public string project_id { get; set; }
        public string private_key_id { get; set; }
        public string private_key { get; set; }
        public string client_email { get; set; }
        public string client_id { get; set; }
        public string auth_uri { get; set; }
        public string token_uri { get; set; }
        public string auth_provider_x509_cert_url { get; set; }
        public string client_x509_cert_url { get; set; }
    }


    public class ServiceAccountAuthExample
    {

        /// <summary>
        /// Authenticating to Google using a Service account
        /// Documentation: https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2#serviceaccount
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="serviceAccountEmail">From Google Developer console https://console.developers.google.com</param>
        /// <param name="serviceAccountCredentialFilePath">Location of the .p12 or Json Service account key file downloaded from Google Developer console https://console.developers.google.com</param>
        /// <returns>AnalyticsService used to make requests against the Analytics API</returns>
        public static AnalyticsReportingService AuthenticateServiceAccount(string serviceAccountEmail, string serviceAccountCredentialFilePath)
        {
            try
            {
                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(serviceAccountCredentialFilePath))
                    throw new Exception("Path to the .p12 service account credentials file is required.");
                if (!File.Exists(serviceAccountCredentialFilePath))
                    throw new Exception("The service account credentials .p12 file does not exist at: " + serviceAccountCredentialFilePath);
                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(serviceAccountEmail))
                    throw new Exception("ServiceAccountEmail is required.");

                // These are the scopes of permissions you need. It is best to request only what you need and not all of them
                string[] scopes = new string[] { AnalyticsReportingService.Scope.Analytics };             // View your Google Analytics data

                // For Json file
                if (Path.GetExtension(serviceAccountCredentialFilePath).ToLower() == ".json")
                {
                    GoogleCredential credential;
                    using (var stream = new FileStream(serviceAccountCredentialFilePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
                    {
                        credential = GoogleCredential.FromStream(stream)
                             .CreateScoped(scopes);
                    }

                    // Create the  Analytics service.
                    return new AnalyticsReportingService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
                    {
                        HttpClientInitializer = credential,
                        ApplicationName = "Analytics Authentication Sample",
                    });
                }
                else if (Path.GetExtension(serviceAccountCredentialFilePath).ToLower() == ".p12")
                {   // If its a P12 file

                    var certificate = new X509Certificate2(serviceAccountCredentialFilePath, "notasecret", X509KeyStorageFlags.MachineKeySet | X509KeyStorageFlags.Exportable);
                    var credential = new ServiceAccountCredential(new ServiceAccountCredential.Initializer(serviceAccountEmail)
                    {
                        Scopes = scopes
                    }.FromCertificate(certificate));

                    // Create the  Analytics service.
                    return new AnalyticsReportingService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
                    {
                        HttpClientInitializer = credential,
                        ApplicationName = "Analytics Authentication Sample",
                    });

                }
                else
                {
                    throw new Exception("Unsupported Service accounts credentials.");
                }

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Create service account AnalyticsService failed" + ex.Message);
                throw new Exception("CreateServiceAccountAnalyticsServiceFailed", ex);
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Authenticating to Google using a Service account
        /// Documentation: https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2#serviceaccount
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="serviceAccountEmail">From Google Developer console https://console.developers.google.com</param>
        /// <param name="key">Key from with in json file   
        /// 
        /// Example:
        /// ServiceAccountAuth tmp = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ServiceAccountAuth>(File.ReadAllText(serviceAccountJsonPath));
        /// 
        /// </param>
        /// <returns>AnalyticsService used to make requests against the Analytics API</returns>
        public static AnalyticsReportingService AuthenticateServiceAccountFromKey(string serviceAccountEmail, string key)
        {
            try
            {
                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(key))
                    throw new Exception("Key is required.");
                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(serviceAccountEmail))
                    throw new Exception("ServiceAccountEmail is required.");

                // These are the scopes of permissions you need. It is best to request only what you need and not all of them
                string[] scopes = new string[] { AnalyticsReportingService.Scope.Analytics };             // View your Google Analytics data


                var credential = new ServiceAccountCredential(new ServiceAccountCredential.Initializer(serviceAccountEmail)
                {
                    Scopes = scopes
                }.FromPrivateKey(key));


                // Create the  Analytics service.
                return new AnalyticsReportingService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
                {
                    HttpClientInitializer = credential,
                    ApplicationName = "Analytics Authentication Sample",
                });

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Create service account AnalyticsService failed" + ex.Message);
                throw new Exception("CreateServiceAccountAnalyticsServiceFailed", ex);
            }
        }

    }
}
```